# C: Declare and execute function in one line

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I can do the following in GCC:

```c
#define INIT_MODULE(name) \
    ({ extern int name(void); name(); })


int main(void) {
    return INIT_MODULE(x);
}
```

Here, the function (expanded from `name`) is created, executed, and returned via a statement expression (GCC extension). This is a minimal repo: I am actually doing some `__asm__` magic to make the `name` function, hence the macro.

I would like to have this be a one-liner, and not call another macro to create the `name` function. In my use case, the caller will only call `INIT_MODULE` once, and does not/should not know the name of the underlying function it is calling.

Basically, I need a way to declare, run, and return the value of a function, all in one line (without using GCC extensions!).

What I DONT want:

```c
// ...

DECL_MODULE(x);

int main(void) {
    return INIT_MODULE(x);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's more to what you want than to simply declare, run and return the function - otherwise you could do it right away in the same manner you already achieved.

The problem that I see is that you want the function to be visible externally, as if it was declared outside of the scope of the caller. And that's clearly not possible, since `#define` just replaces the content of the macro (it can't move it in another point of the code).

Actually, you could use low-level `goto` and some arithmetics, but I'd rather not recommend you that path.

Comment: Using `extern` does not make the function externally visible (in fact, `extern` is the default on functions, so I didn't need to include it anyways). `extern` simply means it is defined somewhere else.The original code I posted does compile and run as expected, but only on GCC. I am simply asking if there is a more portable version that has the same semantics.

Comment: As far as I know, `extern` is not a GCC prerogative, and actually I think it isn't related at all to your issue or your desired behavior. If you **really** don't want your function to be visible outside its scope, why you don't just `#define` the content of the function instead of declaring, defining, and then using it?
As I said, I think there's more to what you asked - try to avoid a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)